# Onde colocar rotate Canvas neste codigo

Tags: html5, canvas

Procurei muito, mais infelizmente não encontrei onde a função rotate do canvas eu conseguiria adicionar neste código.

No html tenho um input type ranger que utilizo para girar a imagem..
O input type pego o valor em graus e salva em uma variavel chamada grausAtual
mais não consigo adaptar esta variavel dentro do ctx.rotate(20 * Math.PI / 180);
e muito também não sei onde eu colocaria este trecho dentro do código abaixo onde gera uma imagem...

```js
  crop = function(){
    //Find the part of the image that is inside the crop box
    var crop_canvas,
        left = $('.overlay').offset().left- $container.offset().left,
        top =  $('.overlay').offset().top - $container.offset().top,
        width = $('.overlay').width(),
        height = $('.overlay').height();
  
  var TO_RADIANS = Math.PI/180; 
    crop_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    crop_canvas.width = width;
    crop_canvas.height = height;

    crop_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image_target, left, top, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
 
 var dataURL=crop_canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
 image_target.src=dataURL;
 orig_src.src=image_target.src;
 
 
 $(image_target).bind("load",function() {
  $(this).css({
   width:width,
   height:height
  }).unbind('load').parent().css({
   top:$('.overlay').offset().top- $('.crop-wrapper').offset().top,
   left:$('.overlay').offset().left- $('.crop-wrapper').offset().left
  })
 });
     
 sessionStorage.setItem('imgAtual', crop_canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
 var url = $('#salvaEtapa').data('url');
 $.colorbox({iframe:true, href:url, width:"60%", height:"80%", opacity:"0.50", title:false});
 $("#escondido").css("visibility","hidden");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

talvez assim:

```
crop_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
crop_canvas.width = width;
crop_canvas.height = height;
crop_canvas.getContext('2d').rotate(grausAtual * Math.PI / 180);
crop_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image_target, left, top, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
```